# How to make Thumb non-draggable after certain Height and Width in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a resizable button whose control template has Thumbs among other things:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="ResizableButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Grid>
<!--Other Stuff-->
    <Thumb Height="3" Cursor="SizeNS" Margin="0 -4 0 0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Thumb Width="3" Cursor="SizeWE" Margin="-4 0 0 0"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    ...
   </Grid>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

Now I want these thumbs should become non-draggable after user has reached certain Height and Width. I tried to use MaxHeight and MaxWidth but that didn't help. Anyone out here can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the Handler of the DragDelta event of the Thumb, where you also change the size of the button(?), you can limit the max Size. Just when the Dragging goes over the allowed size you do not allow the change.

something like:

```
void onDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    //not real code
    if (actualSizeOfTheButton + new Size(e.HorizontalChange, e.VerticalChange)) < MaxSize
    {
       //adjust the size of the button

    }
}
```